# Carregar dados de uma query para uma lightbox

Tags: php, ajax, lightbox

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, e tenho o seguinte código que retorna os resultados de uma query:

```
 $Dados = $conn->getResult();

foreach ($Dados as $Linha):

  echo $Linha['event_name'];
  echo   "<a href='teste.php?id_event={$Linha['id_event']}'>Mais Informações</a><br />";

endforeach;
```

que resulta nisto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora vem a minha dúvida: Como seria possivel eu abrir uma lightbox nesta mesma página sem ter que recarregar ela, pegando todas as informações de certa query quando eu clicar no "mais informações"?

ficando por exemplo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

( Claro que onde esta nome_show seria o nome do show que eu cliquei em mais informações, e assim com todas as outras informações do resultado )

Muito obriagado desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Terá de usar ajax com a criação de formulários interativos para a consulta

por exemplo

na coluna onde você gera o nome, você gera também o id, ou outro atributo identificador dentro do parâmetro da função onclick, por exemplo

```
<a onclick="maisDetalhes($Linha['id_event'])">Mais Informações</a><br />
```

pega esse o id pelo parâmetro na função javascript

```
funtion(id){
var formulario = document.CreateElement("form"); //cria um elemento form
formulario.id = "form1";
formulario.action "paginadosDados.php";
formulario.method = "POST"; //ou get seilá

var input1 = document.CreateElement("input");
input1.type = text;
input1.name = "input1";
input1.value = id; //parâmentro que vc acabou de enviar 

formulario.appendChild(input1);

document.body.appendChild(formulario);

var data = $("#form1").serialize(); //pega o valor do form e envia sem recarregar

$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'paginadosDados.php', // substitua
        data : data,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function()
        {    
aqui vai a animação do carregando...
  } 
  success :  function(response){                        
            if(response.codigo == "0"){ 
           alert(response.mensagem);
  }
  }
  });
}
```

o php só retorna oque você quer e manda os resultados para aquela parte do sucess

exemplo

```
$retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => 'oi');
echo json_encode($retorno);
exit();
```

obs: linque o J-query para ficar mais fácil, esse código escrevi aqui no editor então não foi testado ainda

Comment: Felipe, desculpe pela minha inexperiência, eu não entendi uma coisa, a parte da função sucess,  e o que eu vou colocar de código na página php para poder mostrar  na mesma página ?

Comment: exatamente, o sucess só irá ser executado se a ação for efetuada com sucesso e retornar o código 200, mais isso é outro assunto.